# css grid + react component challenge

Tags: reactjs, css, css-grid

Working on a css grid challenge with React in codepen.

This is the original codepen: https://codepen.io/tallys/pen/bvwZee/
What I have so far: https://codepen.io/al2613/pen/QmOyKo

```
.grid-container {
    border: 2px dashed goldenrod;
    display: inline-grid;
    padding: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-gap: 30px;
}
```

So I got main content area to span across the grid container. However, I'm stuck as to how I can make the aside always 150px and the grid container align nicely with the div at the top?

Comment: I'm really new to grid and I enjoyed it. I don't know if this is the [right answer](https://codepen.io/trinaldi/pen/GxGGvm?editors=1100) It's not the right answer, but you gotta use grid-column-start/end ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to `grid` very nice first try. I think this is a little bit hacky, but...it does the job (I guess)

I don't think the CSS on this snippet will work, but nevertheless, [here's the Pen](https://codepen.io/trinaldi/pen/eMKKqY)...

```js
//Don't edit the JS for the CSS Grid challenge!







class App extends React.Component {
 
 state = {
  sidebarActive: false,
 }

 toggleSidebar() {
  this.setState({sidebarActive: !this.state.sidebarActive})
 }

 render() {
  const buttonText = this.state.sidebarActive ? 'Toggle Sidebar Off' :  'Toggle Sidebar On';
  const {sidebarActive} = this.state
  
  return (
   <div>
    <h1 className="heading">CSS Grid when some sections don't render!</h1>
    <div className="instructions">
     <p>The challenge: Fix the CSS Grid so that the main area takes up all of the available space when the sidebar react component does not render. </p>
    <button onClick={this.toggleSidebar.bind(this)}>{buttonText}</button>
    
    </div>
    <div className="grid-container">
     {sidebarActive && <aside className="sidebar">Sometimes renders!</aside>}
     <main className="main">Main content area that should always take up the rest of the space in the container. </main>
    </div>
   </div>
  );
 }
  
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
// Variables
$brand-color: darkblue;
$brand-section-color: white;
$brand-text-color: #222;

$react-accent: #61dafb;
$react-background: #292c34;

$breakpoint: 768px;
$font-heading: 'Permanent Marker', sans-serif;
$font-default: 'Oswald', sans-serif;

// Styles

body {
 font-family: $font-default;
 margin: 10vh 10vw;
 color: $react-accent;
 background: $react-background;
}


.heading {
 font-family: $font-heading;
}

.instructions {
 padding: 5px 12px 20px 12px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: center;
 background: lighten(adjust-hue($react-background, 30), 7);
 font-size: 1.15rem;
 
 button {
  border: none;
  background: $react-accent;
  font-family: $font-default;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .4s ease;
  
  &:hover, &:active, &:focus {
   background: adjust-hue($react-accent, 210);
  }
 }
}

.grid-container {
 border: 2px dashed goldenrod;
 display: inline-grid;
 grid-template-columns: 150px repeat(1, 1fr);
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
 grid-gap: 30px;
}


.sidebar {
 background: lighten($react-background, 7);
 padding: 10px;
 
 & ~ .main{
   grid-column: auto !important;
 }
}
.main {
 background: darken($react-background, 7);
 display: grid;
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<main id="app"></main>
```

Comment: Awesome approach! :)

Comment: Maybe should explain a little what you're doing, so others can understand it easily. If I'm not missing something, it's just using a sibling selector to modify the grid-column on .main so it goes from "auto" to "span 2" when there's a previous .sidebar sibling. That's awesome.  No need to use the !important btw

Comment: Indeed. When there's no sidebar, the `.main` class takes all the space with the css property `grid-column: span 2;` (The main container has 2 columns, one with 150px and the other filling the rest). 

When then sidebar is present (`&`) I used the sibling selector `~` to change the 'span' of the `.main` class, it now just fill the rest (width - 150px).

Comment: I would not have thought about using sibling selectors! That actually makes things a lot more straight forward. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a **really** late response, but I remembered this challenge... and I couldn't resist.

My approach is fixing the `main` to the second column, while setting the `sidebar` width on the item itself (and a `margin-right` to fake the `grid-gap`), allowing for the first column to be declared as `minmax(0, auto)`.

```
.grid-container {
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, auto) 1fr;
  /*grid-gap: 30px;*/
}
.main {
  grid-column: 2;
}
.sidebar {
  margin-right: 30px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/facundocorradini/pen/eKgVzP

That way the first column will have a zero width if the sidebar is not loaded, and get to the 150px sidebar with when it loads.